# session in node.js with express 4 and socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, socket.io-1.0, express-session

I would like persist some data in session. I am using MongoDB as session store.

I prepared simple code, to do this. But it, doesn't work. I got this error:

> Type Error: Cannot set property 'myVariable' of undefined

And this is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http')
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var get_ip = require('ipware')().get_ip;
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var url = require("url");
var crypto = require('crypto');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var Session      = require('express-session');
var MongoStore  = require('connect-mongo')(Session);
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var url =require('url');



app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(Session({
    cookie: { maxAge: 1000*60*2 } ,
    secret: "session secret" ,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store:new MongoStore({
        db: 'linchat'
    })
}));



server.listen(3000);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('join', function(href, referer){
        socket.request.session.myVariable = 'my session variable value';
        console.log('save on to session');
    })


});
```

What I do wrong?
I use:
"express": "4.12.3",
"socket.io": "1.3.5"

**EDIT**
I try also use express-socket.io-session package:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http')
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var get_ip = require('ipware')().get_ip;
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var url = require("url");
var crypto = require('crypto');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var Session      = require('express-session');
var MongoStore  = require('connect-mongo')(Session);
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var url =require('url');


app.use(cookieParser());


var session = require("express-session")({
    secret: "my-secret",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store:new MongoStore({
        db: 'linchat'
    })
});
app.use(session);
io.use(require("express-socket.io-session")(session));

server.listen(3000);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('join', function(href, referer){
        if(socket.handshake.session.views){
            socket.handshake.session.views +=1;
        } else {
            socket.handshake.session.views =1;
        }
        console.log(socket.handshake.session.views);
    })


});
```

But I console.log() always return '1'

Comment: did you come across this module ? https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session

Comment: Can you look on my update  ?

Comment: how many times the join event actually happens ?

Comment: on body document load I emit join. I refresh page many times and I always got 1 in output

Comment: try opening the same link from another browser too.

Comment: I opened this in Chrome, Firefox and Opera. And I still get 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76638/discussion-between-pawel-brzoski-and-robin).